# Couldn't send mail with NodeMailer and Angular 2+

Tags: node.js, angular, express, angular2-forms, nodemailer

I couldn't send mail with nodemailer and angular 2+. It is showing request fail error.

HTML

```
 <form class="example-form" (ngSubmit)="uptpwd()">  
     <input class="form-control lht" placeholder="Email" type="email" name="email" [(ngModel)]="mailData.to"> 
        <br/> 
        <br/> 
     <button class="lgbtn" type="submit">Enter</button> 
 </form>
```

TS

```
export class ForgotComponent implements OnInit {
 to: string = '';
 mailData = {
   to: this.to,
   subject: 'testing email',
   text: 'This is just a testing email send by the phpsollution.blogspot.com',
 }

 ngOnInit() {}

 uptpwd(mailData) {
  this.auth.uptpwd(this.mailData).subscribe();
 }
}
```

Service

```
   uptpwd(maildata) {
    return this.http.post('http://localhost:3000/sendemail', maildata)
              .map(res => res.json());
   }
```

Server

```
app.post('/sendemail',function(req,res){
let transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
service: 'gmail',
auth: {
    user: 'fe***@gmail.com',
    pass: '******'
}
});

var attachment = (typeof req.body.attachment !="undefined") ? req.body.attachment : '';
var mailOptions = {
     from: "f******@gmail.com",
     to: req.body.to,
     subject: req.body.subject,
     html: req.body.text,


  } 

  smtpTransport.sendMail(mailOptions, function(error, info){
     if(error){
    res.json({status: 'error'});
   }else{
    res.json({status: 'success'});
   };
  });
 });
```

Error

> POST http://localhost:3000/sendmail 500 (Internal Server Error)

Kindly help me. Tell me if I missed anything.

Comment: If your express server is coming back with a 500 response, you should find something meaningful in stdout.  Have you checked your server logs?

Comment: `Response {_body: "<!DOCTYPE html>↵<html lang="en">↵<head>↵<meta char…ib\router\index.js:317:13)</pre>↵</body>↵</html>↵", status: 500, ok: false, statusText: "Internal Server Error", headers: Headers, …}
defaultErrorLogger @ core.js:1350
webpackJsonp.../../../core/esm5/core.js.ErrorHandler.handleError @ core.js:1411
next @ core.js:5376
schedulerFn @ core.js:4223
webpackJsonp.../../../../rxjs/Subscriber.js.SafeSubscriber.__tryOrUnsub @ Subscriber.js:238
webpackJsonp.../../../../rxjs/Subscriber.js.SafeSubscriber.next @ Subscriber.js:185
 This is my error

Comment: That looks like a client-side error log.  What about your server?

Answer (score 1):

I am going to assume you already have your backend running at `localhost:3000`. You need to set up `headers` in your HttpRequest.

```
uptpwd(maildata) {
    let headers = new Headers();
    headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json');
    let options = new RequestOptions({headers: headers});
    return this.http.post('http://localhost:3000/sendemail', maildata, options)
              .map(res => res.json());
   }
```

Comment: My project is running in localhost:4200.I thought mail can send only with localhost:3000. What should i to if my project is running in 4200 ?

Comment: You have to have both frontend and backend running. I'm assuming your backend is running on localhost:3000. localhost:4200 is default port Angular runs on

Comment: @ChauTran can you please check this question too? It's a similar case but for reset password. When I click the link inside the email it navigates to 404 page.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54343388/what-should-be-done-for-fixing-this-reset-password-feature-in-this-angular-code