# What should be done for fixing this reset password feature in this Angular code with Node.js and Nodemailer

Tags: node.js, angular, express, angular6, nodemailer

We are trying to create a reset password feature in Angular 6 with Node.js. The point is that when you click the reset password and fill your email it sends the email with the link of reset password. But the link inside the email is not communicating with Angular. We are using Node.js and Node mailer in the backend. Here is the code:

**Node.js**

```
 async ResetPassword(req, res) {
    if (!req.body.email) {
      return res
        .status(HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR)
        .json({ message: 'Email is required' });
    }

    const userEmail = await User.findOne({
      email: Helpers.lowerCase(req.body.email)
    });
    if (!userEmail) {
      return res
        .status(HttpStatus.CONFLICT)
        .json({ message: 'Email does not exist' });
    }

      const body = {
        email: Helpers.lowerCase(value.email),

      };
            var resettoken = new resetToken({ _userId: user._id, resettoken: crypto.randomBytes(16).toString('hex') });
            resettoken.save(function (err) {
                if (err) { return res.status(500).send({ msg: err.message }); }
                var transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
                    service: '"SendGrid"',
                    auth:
                     {
                      user: 'login',
                      pass: 'password'
                     }
                });
                var mailOptions = {
                    from: 'email',
                    subject: 'Node.js Password Reset',
                    text: 'You are receiving this because you (or someone else) have requested the reset of the password for your account.\n\n' +
                      'Please click on the following link, or paste this into your browser to complete the process:\n\n' +
                      'http://' + req.headers.host + '/new-password/' + resettoken + '\n\n' +
                      'If you did not request this, please ignore this email and your password will remain unchanged.\n'
                }

                transporter.sendMail(mailOptions 
                )          
            })

        .catch(err => {
            res
                .status(HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR)
                .json({ message: 'Error occured' });
        });
    },
```

The link inside email template is not working.

**Route**

```
router.post('/new-password', AuthCtrl.NewPassword);
```

**Angular**

```
      route.queryParams.subscribe(params => {
        this.form.resetToken = params['token'];
      });
    }


  ngOnInit() {
    this.Init();
  }

  Init() {
    this.ResponseResetForm = this.fb.group(
      {
        email: ['', Validators.required, Validators.email],
        newPassword: ['', Validators.required],
        confirmPassword: ['', Validators.required]
      },
      {
        validator: this.Validate.bind(this)
      }
    );
  }

 ...
...

  ResetPassword() {

    this.authService.newPassword(this.ResponseResetForm.value).subscribe(
      data => {
        this.ResponseResetForm.reset();
        setTimeout(() => {
          this.router.navigate(['sign-in']);
        }, 3000);
      },
      err => {

        if (err.error.message) {
          this.errorMessage = err.error.message;
        }
      }
    );
  }
}
```

This part I've added from another code:

```
 route.queryParams.subscribe(params => {
            this.form.resetToken = params['token'];
          });
        }
```

But I don't think it's suitable for our code. Also here is the route for this component in Angular:

```
  {
    path: 'response-reset-password',
    component: ResponseResetComponent
  },
```

How can we make this backend controller work as expected with Angular front-end?

Answer (score 1):

So when you embed a link in your email, that link needs to route to the Angular frontend, not backend:

```
{
   path: 'new-password', // I would suggest changing this path to match your Component. This will also lead to changing the URL being embedded in the ResetPassword email
   component: ResponseResetComponent
}
```

Now, when the user clicks the link in the email, the frontend will be loaded, then you can handle the `token` in the `ResponseResetComponent` to actually send the request to: `router.post('/new-password')` on the backend.

Comment: I am confused. In the email link is this one:
'http://' + req.headers.host + '/new-password/' + resettoken + '\n\n'
in front end as you mentioned new-password but in component I added  route.queryParams.subscribe(params => {
            this.form.resetToken = params['resettoken'];
          });
        }

What should I change, for them communicating with each other?  Can you please explain more detailed in the above my code example?

Comment: you don’t seem to have the route ‘new-password’ setup on your frontend

Comment: and the way you construct your token in the url, it becomes URL params rather than Query Parameters

Comment: Should I just change response-reset-password into new-password and queryParams into URLParams? Then what about http://' + req.headers.host inside the URL in email?

Comment: Did the url in the email end up being your frontend domain? (aka http://localhost:4200/ in development)

Comment: Node runs on localhost:3000 Angular side runs on 4200 at the same time. I read something about set headers but not sure how to use it in this code.

Comment: can you actually screenshot an actual email with that URL?

Comment: It needs to be localhost:4200 aka it needs to be your frontend route.

Comment: Here is the generated link in email: localhost:3000/new-password/7248bcbf485eb145

Comment: When I manually add there localhost:4200 it shows 404 after clicking too.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/187330/discussion-between-chau-tran-and-newtech-lover).